# Stop vscode from open previous tabs when opening folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open vscode using `code .` (in bash on Linux) it starts the editor with my previous tabs opened from the last time I was working in that folder. I want this to stop. How do I make it stop?

The contents of `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` are as follows:

```
{
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "workbench.enableExperiments": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.restoreWindows": "none",
    "files.hotExit": "off",
    "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
    "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
    "workbench.editor.restoreViewState": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "files.restoreUndoStack": false,
    "files.enableTrash": false
}
```

There is no `.vscode` to override these settings in the folder I am opening.

**Work around**

My current work around is to launch vscode with a script that deletes the folder `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage` on exit. This resolves the problem and does not seem to have any unintended side effects, but I would still like to know if there is a "better" solution.